# Possibility to override or re-set the Store Path value on the event

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1, tus, tusdotnet

this is a question I also asked on the [tusdotnet git forum](https://github.com/tusdotnet/tusdotnet/issues/219). I extend my reach here so I could probably get a wide variety of responses and suggestions.

I am new to using the tus upload protocol, currently trying to build a new upload mechanism to replace the existing one in my aspnet mvc solution. I am using the netcore 3.1. So as stated on the git forum, I am trying to find a possibility to override or re-set the destination of my file upload. The old upload mechanism is able to dynamically set the upload destination based on the HttpContext query parameter objects, while on the tusdotnet, I see we basically set the file upload destination during the initial object configuration in our startup pipeline. Is it possible to override this every moment we post a file?

Here is the source code containing the example of tus upload configuration to give the context

```
app.UseTus(context => new DefaultTusConfiguration
{
    UrlPath = "/files",
    Store = new TusDiskStore(@"C:\tusfiles\"), //I want to override or re-set the value per every upload requests
    Events = new Events
    {
        OnBeforeCreateAsync = ctx => //Trying to find the initial event that gets called when we send upload request (cmiiw)
        {
                        string uploadDir = GetUploadStoreDir(eventCtx.HttpContext.Request.Query);
                        ctx.Store = GetUploadDir(eventCtx.HttpContext.Request.Query); //re-set the value here
                        if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetFullPath(uploadDir))) Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadDir);
                        
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnFileCompleteAsync = async eventContext =>
        {
            // eventContext.FileId is the id of the file that was uploaded.
            // eventContext.Store is the data store that was used (in this case an instance of the TusDiskStore) //how can I use the same dynamic value?

            // A normal use case here would be to read the file and do some processing on it.
            ITusFile file = await eventContext.GetFileAsync();
            var result = await BuildFilePlacementAsync(file, eventContext.Store);

            if (!result.Success)
            {
                throw new MyProcessingException("Something went wrong during processing");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I have tried to override the Store from inside one of the event which got something to do with the initial upload process (cmiiw) like `OnBeforeCreateAsync` or `OnAuthorizeAsync` but none of them seems to do the trick so far.